# Add choices to a selectInput

Tags: r, shiny

I have a selectInput with all the possible choices displayed. I want to implement it such that if a user types something in the box and hits enter, that will also be added as a choice.

```
observeEvent(input$mykeypress, {

if(input$mykeypress == 13){

    print(input$selectBox)

}
```

I tried the above code to see if my input changed, but it seems that no matter what extra stuff I type in the selectbox, none of it is recognized.

Anyone have ideas as to have I can recognize anything extra that the user types?

Edit: One other idea I am considering is creating a textInput, and prepopulating it with all the values that I used in my selectbox. Is something like that possible?

Comment: See autocomplete feature of jQuery

Comment: @MaxZoom I don't want the user to be selecting from a pre-populated list. I want to allow them to type any input they please and have it show up upon pressing enter

Comment: You should build the `selectInput` in the server using `renderUI`. Then you can make the choices reactive.

Comment: Sounds more like you want `textInput` rather than a `selectInput`. http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/textInput.html

Comment: I think you guys aren't fully understanding exactly what I want. To clarify, in a selectInput with multiple = TRUE, you can allow all the selections to show up by using the selected feature. I then want the user to be able to add selections by simply typing then pressing enter. The user should also be able to click on selections and delete them by pressing the backspace key (normal functionality of a selectInput)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I ended up figuring it out, because the selectizeInput just wraps around selectize.js, in your selectizeInput you can use the argument: options = list(create = TRUE), and the user can add words easily.

Comment: Have you by any chance also tested whether "removeOption" works too?

Comment: I don't think I tested that out unfortunately. I think in my case, I was able to select any of the items in the selectizeInput and remove it my clicking the item and then hitting backspace on my keyboard. After that, I implemented a button that would save with the new values.

Comment: i'll ask around on the seletize.js github page. thanks for replying

Comment: Hm i finally ended up testing it, but it doesn't seem to work for me. I tried installing pacakage selectize.js but I get an error that it is not available for R 3.4.3. Am I doing something wrong?
Do you have an example of a working selectizeInput with the create option?

Comment: I unfortunately haven't worked with RShiny in a while, and I don't have the code that I wrote for RShiny available to me. From what I remember though, I didn't have to install anything other than RShiny itself. Can you provide more details on the error?

Comment: well... even if I run the example from the website it doesn't work. 
here is the demo app link on shiny site. It also doesn't work on the site it seems

Comment: For the user to be able to type and add what he typed, it must be starting from an empty field. This can be achieved by passing "" as first entry. Example `selectizeInput(..., choices = c("choose one" = "", "A", "B", "C"), options=list(create=T))`